# Displaying to divs in front of picture in div

Tags: html, css

Good day, I know that my title is chaotic but I was trying to find an answer for about 2 hours.

```
<div id="lightbox">
    <img src="blabla.png">
    <div href="#" id="next" onClick="next(1)"></div>
    <div href="#" id="prev" onClick="prev(1)"></div>
</div>
```

Also #lightbox is z-indexed. Can I make those next and prev divs appear in front of that picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#next` and `#prev` need to have a `z-index`, assuming they are absolute positioned. If the image has an absolute or relative positioning too, then the `z-index` of `#next` and `#prev` needs to be higher than the image `z-index`.

If `#lightbox` has an absolute positioning then you would need a container for all of the items that has a relative positioning.

Comment: Can you be please more specific with that container. Don't know what you are talking about. But I have z-index higher on prev and next as on image

Comment: Anything that has an absolute position needs to have a parent that it's relative to. If not specified it will be relative to 'body'. If you want to position your buttons they need to be relative to something. If you post your css as well I can tell you in more detail how to fix it. Or better still, create a fiddle.

Comment: #lightBox {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
 z-index: 999;
 top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#next {
 z-index: 900;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: blue;
 float: right;
 display: none;
}
#prev {
 z-index: 900;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
 display: none;
}
img#lb {
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

Comment: I have created a fiddle for you. Made some changes so hopefully this will be useful: https://jsfiddle.net/0Le38r8q/
Just a note: your css is referencing #lightBox instead of #lightbox as used in your html.

Comment: thank you very much. It worked without above container. :) Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)